# Cannot Update ADO Recordset in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, ado, recordset, vba

I'm creating a recordset using excel range as data source. the code is

```
    Sub Hello()

    Dim xlXML             As Object
    Dim adoRecordset      As Object
    Dim rng               As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:C6")
    Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
    adoRecordset.CursorLocation = 3
    adoRecordset.Open xlXML, CursorType:=2, LockType:=3

    adoRecordset.Movefirst

    adoRecordset.Fields(1) = 1000 'this is the error line
    adoRecordset.Update

    Set adoRecordset = Nothing
    Set xlXML = Nothing

    End Sub
```

I'm unable to update the dataset, getting the error "Multiple step operation generated errors. Check each value (-2147217887)". I don't know where i'm going wrong. I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the table you are trying to populate?  The "Multiple-Step operation generated errors" occurs when something related to a specific field is wrong e.g. `adoRecordset.Fields(1)` is of type `bit` and you try to put 1000 in there.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think before adding a new line or editing an existing line in a recordset you have to put:

```
adoRecordset.Edit
' OR
adoRecordset.AddNew
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason is that a `RecordSet` derived from a `Range` is, by default, immutable - as effectively identified in the post by Andrew [here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/).

Assuming the source range has these contents (to eliminate 'datatype' issues)

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $A$1 | $B$1 | $C$1 |
| 2 | $A$2 | $B$2 | $C$2 |
| 3 | $A$3 | $B$3 | $C$3 |
| 4 | $A$4 | $B$4 | $C$4 |
| 5 | $A$5 | $B$5 | $C$5 |
| 6 | $A$6 | $B$6 | $C$6 |

then a working version of the OP's code would be

```
Sub Hello()

    Dim xlXML             As Object
    Dim ElementNode       As Object
    Dim AttributeNodes    As Object
    Dim Child             As Object
    Dim adoRecordset      As Object
    Dim rng               As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:C6")
    Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
    xlXML.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'"
    
    Set ElementNode = xlXML.SelectSingleNode("xml/x:PivotCache/s:Schema/s:ElementType")
    ElementNode.setAttribute "rs:updatable", "true"
    
    Set AttributeNodes = xlXML.SelectNodes("xml/x:PivotCache/s:Schema/s:AttributeType")
    For Each Child In AttributeNodes
        Child.setAttribute "rs:write", "true"
    Next Child
        
    adoRecordset.CursorLocation = 3
    adoRecordset.Open xlXML, CursorType:=2, LockType:=3

    adoRecordset.Movefirst

    adoRecordset.Fields(1) = 1000
    adoRecordset.Update

    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset adoRecordset    'added to reflect the update on the worksheet
    Set adoRecordset = Nothing
    Set xlXML = Nothing

End Sub
```